# Format string bold at a bookmark location

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am a newbie and am making a userform that inputs data into a letter.  There is a string that I need to bold and underline.

```
    With .Bookmarks("bidDate").Range.InsertBefore
      .Text = inputBidM & " " & inputBidD & ", " & inputBidY
      .Font.Bold = True
      .Font.Underline = True
    End With
```

I found this http://computer-programming-forum.com/1-vba/8e9aacaf425425ad.htm to get what I have above but am getting a Compile Error: Invalid or Unqualified reference.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Here is the code for that section.  I have everything else commented out.

```
Private Sub startButton_Click()
 ' Inserting Addendum Info from fill in boxes
 With ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("addenDate").Range.InsertBefore inputAddenM & " " & inputAddenD & ", " & inputAddenY
    .Bookmarks("addenDateA").Range.InsertBefore inputAddenM & " " & inputAddenD & ", " & inputAddenY
    .Bookmarks("contractNo").Range.InsertBefore inputContractNo
    .Bookmarks("contractNoA").Range.InsertBefore inputContractNo
    .Bookmarks("fapNo").Range.InsertBefore inputFAPNo
    .Bookmarks("descrip").Range.InsertBefore inputDescrip
    .Bookmarks("addenNo").Range.InsertBefore inputAddenNo
    .Bookmarks("addenNoA").Range.InsertBefore inputAddenNo
    .Bookmarks("addenNoB").Range.InsertBefore inputAddenNo
    .Bookmarks("bidDate").Range.Text inputBidM & " " & inputBidD & ", " & inputBidY
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Underline = True
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, I find this approach preferable to the one you marked as an Answer, the reason being the use of a Range rather than Selection object. The only problem with your code is that you don't need `.InsertBefore`. Remove that and it should work. The reason working with a Range is preferable to working with a Selection is that: 1) The screen stays quiet; 2) execution is faster; 3) You have better control over where/what's happening in the code; 4) You can work with multiple Ranges, but there can be only one Selection.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work.  I could be missing something though.

Comment: Since you don't show us an entire macro AND you don't describe "HOW" it doesn't work, that doesn't make it easy to trouble-shoot. But if this is all that's in your macro, you need to use `ActiveDocument` in front of `.Bookmarks`. You might want to use the [edit] link to put the full macro (including `Sub` and `End Sub`) into your Question...

Comment: Sorry about that.  Modified to include more code.

Comment: Ah, OK :-)  Since it's hard to read code in a Comment, I'll copy the code you show to an Answer, correct it so that it will run and explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `With` keyword lets you perform multiple actions on an object without needing to type the object out for each line. The code you show *could* be written without the `With` and `End With` by putting `ActiveDocument` in front of each `.Bookmarks` line. You can see how this saves time typing and it can be easier to read :-)

Since you want to do more with the last bookmark than just insert text, you can add (nest) another `With...End With` to let you work with that Range, something like this:

```
Private Sub startButton_Click()
  ' Inserting Addendum Info from fill in boxes
  With ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("addenDate").Range.InsertBefore inputAddenM & " " & inputAddenD & ", " & inputAddenY
    .Bookmarks("addenDateA").Range.InsertBefore inputAddenM & " " & inputAddenD & ", " & inputAddenY
    .Bookmarks("contractNo").Range.InsertBefore inputContractNo
    .Bookmarks("contractNoA").Range.InsertBefore inputContractNo
    .Bookmarks("fapNo").Range.InsertBefore inputFAPNo
    .Bookmarks("descrip").Range.InsertBefore inputDescrip
    .Bookmarks("addenNo").Range.InsertBefore inputAddenNo
    .Bookmarks("addenNoA").Range.InsertBefore inputAddenNo
    .Bookmarks("addenNoB").Range.InsertBefore inputAddenNo
     With .Bookmarks("bidDate").Range
        .Text = inputBidM & " " & inputBidD & ", " & inputBidY
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Underline = True
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Also thank you for helping me understand more of what is actually going on with the commands.

Comment: What is the difference between `.Text` and `.InsertBefore`/`.InsertAfter`?

Comment: `.Text` will replace whatever is in the `Range` (or `Selection`); think of it like selecting something, then typing on the keyboard. (`Selection.TypeText` will do the same, if the selection spans text instead of being a blinking cursor). The two "Insert" commands will place the new text in front of / after the given Range or Selection. Think of it like first pressing left- or right-arrow, then typing so that everything is retained. So if your bookmarks [bracketed] placeholder text in the document using `.Text` would remove the placeholder; the "Insert" methods would leave the placeholder.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The following does work:

```
Sub test()

    With Selection
        .GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="bidDate"
        .Text = "blah blah blah"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Underline = True
    End With

End Sub
```

A colon before `.Bookmarks` is only possible when another `With` statement was used. That is why you are getting the error message.